# Org protocol capture working for months then stopped suddenly without any proper error message

Tags: emacs, org-mode, emacsclient

I have two emacs setups runnning with the help of chemacs2, one with doom config and one with vannila emacs with few configurations in org-mode. This has been running for few months now, and then today I get this following error. Even with `(setq debug-on-error t)` I get no message/information except this one.

```
$ emacsclient -c --alternate-editor='' org-protocol://capture://link/title/encoded
Waiting for Emacs...
>>> *ERROR*: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil  <<<
```

Here is the startup sequence

```
$ emacsclient -c --alternate-editor='' "org-protocol://capture://link/title/encoded"
emacsclient: connect: Connection refused

Warning: due to a long standing Gtk+ bug
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/221
Emacs might crash when run in daemon mode and the X11 connection is unexpectedly lost.
Using an Emacs configured with --with-x-toolkit=lucid does not have this problem.
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/00debian.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/00debian.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...done
Loading debian-ispell...done
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...done
Loading /home/vanangamudi/kadal/aalar/emacs/.emacs.d/chemacs.el (source)...
Loading /home/vanangamudi/emacs/vanilla.d/init.el (source)...
Followed link to /home/vanangamudi/kadal/aalar/emacs/vanilla.d/config.org
Wrote /home/vanangamudi/emacs/vanilla.d/config.el
Wrote /home/vanangamudi/emacs/vanilla.d/config.el
Wrote /home/vanangamudi/emacs/vanilla.d/config.el
Wrote /home/vanangamudi/emacs/vanilla.d/config.el
Wrote /home/vanangamudi/emacs/vanilla.d/config.el
Wrote /home/vanangamudi/emacs/vanilla.d/config.el
Wrote /home/vanangamudi/emacs/vanilla.d/config.el
Tangled 7 code blocks from config.org
Loading /home/vanangamudi/emacs/vanilla.d/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/vanangamudi/emacs/vanilla.d/config.el (source)...done
Loaded ~/emacs/vanilla.d/config.el
Loading /home/vanangamudi/emacs/vanilla.d/init.el (source)...done
Loading /home/vanangamudi/kadal/aalar/emacs/.emacs.d/chemacs.el (source)...done
Loading /home/vanangamudi/emacs/vanilla.d/init.el (source)...
Loading /home/vanangamudi/emacs/vanilla.d/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/vanangamudi/emacs/vanilla.d/config.el (source)...done
Loaded ~/emacs/vanilla.d/config.el
Loading /home/vanangamudi/emacs/vanilla.d/init.el (source)...done
Starting Emacs daemon.
Emacs daemon should have started, trying to connect again
Waiting for Emacs...
*ERROR*: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the wrong format for the command. Try this:

```
emacsclient "org-protocol://capture?template=L&url=www.test.com/SomeLink&title=Something&body=Site"
```

Note that I defined the template key to be used in the URL. Make sure you have a template with that key. The one I used was:

```
     ("L" "Protocol Link" entry (file+headline "~/capture-test.org" "Captured")
      "* %? [[%:link][%:description]] \nCaptured On: %U")
```

It is also worth to read the documentation of the function `org-protocol-capture` (by typing `C-h f org-protocol-capture`).